# Панель внизу экрана

Tags: android, ui, design

Как сделать панель внизу экрана, с помощью которой можно было бы переключаться между активностями, как в новом дизайне приложения Вконтакте для android?

Comment: Попробуйте BottomNavigationView

Comment: Можно использовать [BottomSheetBehavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.html)